How do I get the diagram shown in the yellow box below?
Below is an image of the inner workings of the HB100 microwave sensor.
I assume the person measured the length and found it 3/4 lambda long.
In the video he mentions it is open, short, open then short circuit from the graph in the yellow box. What does open, short mean in terms of how it aids in the 10.52GHz from resonating? How does he know how many short and open circuits there are?

Resources:

YouTube Link

Datasheet



"In the video" - A link to that video would help, as this picture is rather out of context.


How does he know how many short and open circuits there are?

is mistaken.  There are not open and short circuits.
There are places along the microstrip where the voltage-current relationship (after including the effects of reflection) is the same as either an open or short circuit.
The mechanical equivalent are antinodes and nodes in a transverse (compression) standing wave.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QbmvunlQR0  The quarter-wave shift phenomenon between density and displacement in the mechanical demonstration parallels voltage and current in the RF circuit.

This is a fundamental property of T-lines to invert the impedance of odd multiples of a 1/4 wave stub from the open end to short at the source because the wave reflections oppose the repeating sent waves. This becomes a notch filter or provides a very low impedance at this resonant frequency.
At even multiples, e.g., 1/2, 1, 3/2 wavelengths, the waves for voltage and current are in sync, so the load impedance is not transformed. If unterminated, this T-line becomes a resonant circuit equivalent to a lumped || LC filter but damped by any parallel R.
Continue your search by examining how "transmission line stubs" are used in VHF/UHF designs.
If the signal wavelengths occur < 10% of the T-line delay here is a variable impedance transformation that is now a function of frequency or its inverse, wavelength.
Anecdotal
When pay TV first came out by jamming the video between the Chroma and audio sub-carrier channels on a cable TV network, RF Engineers, like many I knew, found the best quality coax to make a 1/4 wave notch filter for a certain mid-band channel when we were young and underpaid. A rigid helicoil had the highest Q, next was a semi-rigid coax.  So when the LC impedance goes to 0, then the Resistance in micro-ohms makes a big difference in the dB depth of the notch, while temperature coefficients and rigidity can affect tuning stability greatly.

By "the waves for voltage and current are in sync" do you mean synchronized with each other or with the same variables, measured at the end of the strip?

I meant in sync.  so the impedance is transferred to source for even multiples.  Amplitude depends on Zo matching. so these are variables. But bandwidth is another variable which affects fringe effects like return loss off centre.
